# vscode error while fetching extensions XHR failed

Tags: vpn, marketplace

I have two machines (Windows-10 and Fedora-38), each with VScode running on it.  When Private Internet Access (PIA) is disabled on the Linux machine, VScode can access the extensions marketplace.  When PIA is enabled, I get: "Error while fetching extensions. XHR failed".

On the W10 machine, it doesn't matter whether PIA is enabled or not, I get that same error.  I have 52 extensions installed on the W10 machine, so XHR failure is a new problem. PIA has been installed for at least a couple of years, and it wasn't a headache before. The W10 machine has been through at least two system updates since I remember it working without complaining about XHR.

I've read related StackOverflow posts on the subject and tried the recommendations (Use the proxy support for extensions = On, Override, Fallback) on the W10 machine, but nothing has worked so far.  I have not yet tinkered with the Fedora machine's VScode settings because I can just disable PIA and get access to the extensions marketplace. One suggestion asked if I could access https://vscode.dev/ - sure, regardless of PIA's current state.

I'd like to facilitate extension marketplace access (WITH PIA VPN active) on both machines. Suggestions?